# web_1 | standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
ENV WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR $WORKDIR
COPY package*.json $WORKDIR
RUN npm install --production --no-cache



FROM node:12-alpine
ENV USER node
ENV WORKDIR /home/$USER/app
WORKDIR $WORKDIR
COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/node_modules node_modules
RUN chown $USER:$USER $WORKDIR
COPY --chown=node . $WORKDIR
# In production environment uncomment the next line
#RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER && chmod -R g-s,o-rx /home/$USER && chmod -R o-wrx $WORKDIR



EXPOSE 4000

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ["chmod", "+x","/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh


until nc -z -w 2 mongo 27017 && echo 'mongo is ready for connections' && node artifacts/db-reset.js && npm start; do sleep 2; done
```

I am trying to run NodeGoat using docker but when I run the docker-compose up command it gives me:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory" error.
```

This is a link to my full repo. https://github.com/194817w/NodeGoat

Comment: How are you launching the container?  Is there any possibility the `entrypoint.sh` script has DOS line endings but it's running in a Linux container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I was using the DOS line endings for my entrypoint.sh. I've change to linux endings and everything is working now thanks.

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @Aisha